# Two spaces which are coverings of each other

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be non-homeomorphic spaces. Can $X$ be a cover of $Y$ and vice versa?

Does the answer change if we have a nicer class of spaces eg. path-connected CW-complexes/manifolds?